# Group By and Aggregation issue to pick up latest value for certain column- PSQL

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to generate new table from existing dataset in postgres db as below, hope someone can assist on my query to generate new table that takes latest value from url 1 and gets remaining columns group by

**available table** :

| name | type | url1 | url2 | date | days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | online | http1 | abclink1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| First | online | http2. | abclink1 | 2022-01-25 | 4 |
| Second | offline | http10. | xyzlink232r4 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |

**new table** needed is as below - First, group by should only be applicable on name and type and give http2 for url1 as that is the latest value based on date.

| name | type | url1 | url2 | date | Max days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | online | http2. | abclink1 | 2022-01-25 | 4 |
| Second | offline | http10. | xyzlink232r4 | 2022-01-12 | 1 |

Tried with group by name, type, url1, url2 and it returns same 3 rows as they form separate group  due to varying url1 for same name. None of the columns are unique in this table.

```
select name, type, url1, url2,max(date), max(days) from table
group by name, type, url1, url2
```

~pk

Comment: What is your answerable programming question? Please heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: (When *group by should only be applicable on name and type*, what is the idea in coding `group by name, type, url1, url2`?

Comment: i think once we have aggregation in a query, other values must be in either aggregated or group by, correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT name,
           type,
           url1,
           url2,
           date,
           days,
           rank() over (partition by name, type order by days desc, date desc) as rank
    FROM xyz
) tab
WHERE rank = 1;
```

Comment: Why `order by days desc, date desc` when the requirement reads `latest value based on date`? Please argue, in your answer, why selecting max(date) isn't enough after group/partition.

Comment: I used order by days and date based on query posted in question `max(date), max(days)`. But yea, in original question is just date, anyway you can always remove days and leave only date

Comment: Thank you Boorsuk for quick answer.  Also would like to understand partition and order by columns, if there are more attributes in the table do we need to have all those in the partition list and this list is similar to group by columns? order by days is also helping pick latest value for the name and is helpful when multiple values of days per name is available.

Comment: @user20128530 no you dont need to list all columns in partition by, just the columns on which you wana group, also you can order this set of data of different set of columns.
sry. for the late response